# How to get a number starting from 4 and transforming it?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have the following `3` operations:

1. Add `4` at the end of the number ( 13 becomes 134 ).
2. Add `0` at the end of the number ( 13 becomes 130 ).
3. If number is even divide it by 2.

Using these operations and starting from `4` I have to compute a user input number and output the value of each operation made. For `n` = `7` it should output `3 3 1 3` because `((((4 / 2) / 2) * 10) + 4) / 2 = 7`. I just can't find a solution. I just wrote some code to output the result for `n` = 5. `n` is smaller than `100.000`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int one( int n )
{
    printf( "1 " );
    return n * 10 + 4;
}

int two( int n )
{
    printf( "2 " );
    return n * 10;
}

int three( int n )
{
    printf( "3 " );
    return n / 2;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf( "%d", &n );
    three( two( three( three( n ))));
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone please help me?
Thank you!

Edit!
The following picture will show expected results for some input.
[image]

Comment: This makes no sense to me: How is each operation chosen, how is it related to the user input, what is the actual algorithm here?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: @UnholySheep This is my problem. I don't know. I just have to take a number, maybe have a variable initialized to `4` and compute the number.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar I can do it on paper, but even on paper I can do it only on a small set of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by dynamic programming.

Say the user input n = K. You can reach to K in three ways.

```
If K has 4 or 0 as last digit, then from the number formed by removing last digit.  
Else from 2 * K
```

So if you prepopulate ways to reach every number, then you can backtrack from input number back to starting number 4.

Lets `S` is the array storing a pair of numbers i.e. previous number and method from which `S` can be reached. There can be multiple ways to reach S but you can store any.
so as example, `S[44] = {88,3} or {4,1}`.

But the difficult task is to find upper limit of array till where to prepopulate. Maximum value of N can be 100. 100 can be achieved from 10, so not a problem. Lets check for smaller numbers

```
99 <- 198 <- 396 <- 792 <- 1584 <- 158
98 <- 196 <- 392 <- 784 <- 78
```

So pre-populating data is required till S[1584]

Let `M = 1584`
Lets fill the array `S`. Initially set all indices of `S` to `null`

```
for i from 1 to M
    if i has 0 or 4 at unit place
        S[i] = {no formed by removing unit place digit, method 1 or 2}

        There are gaps remaining which were to be filled by method 3, lets also fill them, i/2 and furthur if i is even
        J = i
        k = i/2
        while(j is even and S[k] is null)
            S[k] = {j, 3}
            j = k;
            k = j/2
```

When all S all filled, lets do for N = 7 giving in original problem
Some values for S are as follows

```
S[1] = {2,3}
S[2] = {4,3}
S[3] = {6,3}
S[4] = {0,1}
S[5] = {10,3}
S[6] = {12,3}
S[7] = {14,3}
S[8] = {16,3}
S[9] = {18,3}
S[10] = {1,2}
S[11] = {22,3}
S[12] = {24,3}
S[13] = {26,3}
S[14] = {1,1}

S[7] = {14,3} , so store 3 and check for 14
S[14] = {1,1}, so store 1 and check for 1
S[1] = {2,3}, so store 3 and check for 2
S[2] = {4,2}, so store 3 and 4 is reached, and you are done.
```

Print stored value in reverse format are 3,3,1,3.

Comment: @Timotel does it help?

Comment: I think I have written a simpler method, but the idea is similar to yours. I start from `number` and reach `4`, store operation number in an array and print the `array` in reverse order.

Comment: how do you find the way to reach 4?

Comment: Well, I was not sure what dynamic programming is and I asked someone to tell me something about your answer and taught me how to solve the problem. I use an array to store operation number. Let's say `number` is `18723`. If `number`'s last digit is 4 then cut it, write `1` on position `i` in the array and increment `i`. If `number`'s last digit is `4` then cut it, write `2` on position `i` in the array and increment `i`. Else multiply `number` by `2` and write `3` in the array on position `i` and increment `i`. Done it in a `while( number != 4)` and then write array in reverse order.

Comment: `18723-37446-74892-149784-14978-29956-59912-119824-11982-23964-2396-4792-9584-958-1916-3832-7664-766-1532-3064-306-612-1224-122-244-24-2-4`

Comment: You are right. you will always reach 4 in that way. Though it may not be the shortest. Anyway my solution also does not give shortest way.